# React router v4 - activeStyle and activeClassName not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

For some reason, my activeStyle and activeClassName props for NavLink component are not working. Am I doing something wrong here? Maybe I am using v3 syntax?

```
import React from "react";
import {NavLink, Route} from "react-router-dom";

//...Imports of router components

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink activeStyle={{ color:'red' }} to="archives">
                   Archives
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="settings">
                    Settings
                </NavLink>
                //...Routes are here
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only problem is missing slashes,  meaning:

```
<NavLink activeStyle={{ color:'red' }} to="/archives"> Archives </NavLink>    

<NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/settings"> Settings </NavLink>
```

Should work.

Comment: It was it! I dont know why I was so stupid to not try it :D